# make arguments with qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

I have imported an existing Makefile-based project into Qt. So no qmake, no CMake, no nothing, just one `makefile`. All is well, but the project is very large and I want to build it in parallel (`make -j40` or whatever). How do I set up `make` arguments in Qt Creator?

Of course I can always run `make` from the shell but hey I want pretty buttons and stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! In Projects (the wrench icon) / Build Settings / Build Steps / Details there are make arguments. One can also add custom build steps that are not in the makefile!